# I want to host nodejs instance for every virtual application with only one single physical location of folder in azure app service

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice

I am successfully able to deploy nodejs application in azure app service.

I also able to deploy nodejs against multiple virtual application in azure app service.
To run multiple nodejs application against virtual application I have to deploy complete folder into new folder path and map it to virtual application.
I want to achieve it with single physical folder only.

Let me give a sample below.

```
Sr.No     Virtual Application             Physical Path
1.        /dev1/App                        /wwwroot/dev1/App
2.        /dev2/App                        /wwwroot/dev2/App
```

**I could able to achieve the above scenario.**

*I am trying to achieve the below one.*

```
Sr.No     Virtual Application             Physical Path
1.        /dev1/App                        /wwwroot/a/b/app
2.        /dev2/App                        /wwwroot/a/b/app
```

I am using iisnode + web.config.

Comment: It's not possible. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**In short, it's impossible.**

You can deploy multiple projects in single azure web app like the first scenario you provided.

A [virtual directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis) is a directory name (also referred to as path) that you specify in IIS and map to a physical directory on a local or remote server. The directory name then becomes part of the application's URL, and users can request the URL from a browser to access content in the physical directory.

If you host multiple virtual app with a single physical directory, it is **more difficult to discover the actual physical file structure on your server because the URL does not map directly** to the root of the site.